# Extract data/price from a Span Class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I run this code:

```
(BeautifulSoup((requests.get('https://www.theglobeandmail.com/investing/markets/stocks/ENB-T/').text), 'html.parser')).find_all('span', {'class':'barchart-overview-field-value'})[0]
```

I get:

[this span element with a bunch of information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVSZX.png)

How can I extract the price 39.21 from the span class above?

would appreciate any advice

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.theglobeandmail.com/investing/markets/stocks/ENB-T/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'barchart-overview-field-value'})
barchart_field = span.find("barchart-field")
print(barchart_field["value"])
```

result

```
39.21
```

Info: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines to ur code:

```
barchart = span.find('barchart-field')

value = barchart['value']

print(value)
```

Output:

```
39.21
```